# IntelliJ / Android Studios: hide the project pane

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

I'm quite new to mac but have managed to figure out a lot of the shortcuts but this one baffles me.

In intelliJ / Android Studios, occassionally, I need to hide some of the panes so that I have more space to see my code. The shortcut to hide the project pane on the left side of the screen when I hover over it has the following shortcut displayed:

[image]

I can see a shift there, but the circle with the arrow is nowhere to be found on my keyboard. Also, the click with the Alt button makes no sense as a normal click will hide the project pane in any case.

Where is the arrow out of the circle button on my macbook pro?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That is the Escape (<kbd>esc</kbd> / <kbd>⎋</kbd>) key.

You can find more explanations for [Mac Keyboard Symbols here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18802?viewlocale=en_US).

The click with <kbd>option</kbd>/<kbd>alt</kbd>/<kbd>⌥</kbd> function exists to hide the entire sidebar. The sidebar can contain multiple panes, such as the Favorites pane. Without holding <kbd>option</kbd>/<kbd>alt</kbd>/<kbd>⌥</kbd>, it will hide only the Project pane and expand any other pane in the sidebar (if none, it will hide the sidebar).